# ASP.NET Core Web API - cannot convert from 'Identity.ApplicationUser' to 'MediatR.IRequest<Response.AdminUserListDto>'

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, fluentvalidation

In my ASP.NET Core-6 Web API, I have this code:

Identity.ApplicationUser:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool? IsAdmin { get; set; }
}
```

Helper:

```
public class ServiceResult<T> : ServiceResult
{
    public T Data { get; set; }

    public ServiceResult(T data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }

    public ServiceResult(T data, ServiceError error) : base(error)
    {
        Data = data;
    }

    public ServiceResult(ServiceError error) : base(error)
    {

    }
}

public class ServiceResult
{
    public bool Successful => this.Error == null;

    public ServiceError Error { get; set; }

    public ServiceResult(ServiceError error)
    {
        if (error == null)
        {
            error = ServiceError.DefaultError;
        }

        Error = error;
    }

    public ServiceResult() { }

    public static ServiceResult Failed(ServiceError error)
    {
        return new ServiceResult(error);
    }

    public static ServiceResult<T> Failed<T>(ServiceError error)
    {
        return new ServiceResult<T>(error);
    }

    public static ServiceResult<T> Failed<T>(T data, ServiceError error)
    {
        return new ServiceResult<T>(data, error);
    }

    public static ServiceResult<T> Success<T>(T data)
    {
        return new ServiceResult<T>(data);
    }
}
```

I am using ASP.NET IdentityDbContext.

Request wrapper:

```
public interface IRequestWrapper<T> : IRequest<ServiceResult<T>>
{
}
```

Request handler wrapper:

```
public interface IRequestHandlerWrapper<in TRequest, TResponse> : IRequestHandler<TRequest, ServiceResult<TResponse>>
    where TRequest : IRequestWrapper<TResponse>
{
}
```

Then the DTO:

```
public class AdminUserListDto : IRequest
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
    public bool? IsAdmin { get; set; }
    public void Register(TypeAdapterConfig config)
    {
        config.NewConfig<ApplicationUser, AdminUserListDto>();
    }
}
```

DependencyInjection:

```
public static class DependencyInjection
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddApplication(this IServiceCollection services)
    {

        // Register Application Health Checks
        services.AddHealthChecks()
            .AddCheck<ApplicationHealthCheck>(name: "MY API");

        // Register Fluent Validation service
        services.AddValidatorsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        // Register MediatR Services
        services.AddMediatR(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(UnhandledExceptionBehaviour<,>));
        services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(ValidationBehaviour<,>));
        services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(PerformanceBehaviour<,>));

        return services;
    }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// Add library project references for DependencyInjection
builder.Services.AddApplication();
```

CreateAdminUserCommand:

```
public class CreateAdminUserCommand : IRequestWrapper<AdminUserListDto>
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool? IsAdmin { get; set; }
}
```

CreateAdminUserCommandValidator:

```
public class CreateAdminUserCommandValidator : AbstractValidator<CreateAdminUserCommand>
{
    public CreateAdminUserCommandValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(u => u.UserName)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("User Name field is required. ERROR!");

        RuleFor(u => u.MobileNumber)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Mobile Number field is required. ERROR!");

        RuleFor(u => u.Email)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Email field is required. ERROR!");

        RuleFor(u => u.Password)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Password field is required. ERROR!");
    }
}
```

Lastly, I have
:

```
public class CreateAdminUserCommandHandler : IRequestHandlerWrapper<CreateAdminUserCommand, AdminUserListDto>
{
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;
    private readonly IAppDbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly RoleManager<ApplicationRole> _roleManager;
    public CreateAdminUserCommandHandler(IMediator mediator, IAppDbContext dbContext, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<ApplicationRole> roleManager)
    {
        _mediator = mediator;
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
    }
    public async Task<ServiceResult<AdminUserListDto>> Handle(CreateAdminUserCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var adminUser = new ApplicationUser()
        {
            MobileNumber = request.MobileNumber,
            UserName = request.UserName,
            Email = request.Email,
            IsAdmin = request.IsAdmin
        };
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(adminUser, request.Password);

        return ServiceResult.Success(_mediator.Send<AdminUserListDto>(adminUser));
    }
}
```

After success, I expect it to return:

**AdminUserListDto**

But I got this error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Identity.ApplicationUser' to 'MediatR.IRequest<Response.AdminUserListDto>'

Then **adminUser** is highlighted in:

> return ServiceResult.Success(_mediator.Send(adminUser));

How do I resolve this?

Thank you

Comment: You need to map from ApplicationUser to AdminUserListDto and send that to mediatr, because that is what your handler expects.

Comment: @Neil - I updated AdminUserListDto with mapping, Also added DependencyInjection and Program.cs. See the updated code. Yet the error is still there. What else do I need to do?

Comment: I've just re-read your handler, why are you calling mediator when creating the result?

Comment: @Neil - I did that because I want to return the content of AdminUserListDto after success

Comment: @Neil - I use Mapster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably confusing `mediator` and `mapper`.
What you need is:

```
return ServiceResult.Success(_mapper.Map<AdminUserListDto>(adminUser));
```

Comment: I am using mapster